# Using a variable inside a CDATA string in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, console, cdata

Suppose that I have a Class with a multiline string like this:

```
Public Class HelpSection

    ' This process name (Example: 'MyProcess.exe')
    Public Shared ReadOnly ThisProcess As String = 
        Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName

    Public Shared ReadOnly Syntax As String = 
        <a><![CDATA[
            [+] Syntax:

                ThisProcess (SWITCH)=(VALUE) (IN FILE)
        ]]></a>.Value

End Class
```

And now, when I call the multiline string:

```
Console.WriteLine(HelpSection4.Syntax)
```

It will print this:

```
ThisProcess (SWITCH)=(VALUE) (IN FILE)
```

But I would like to print automatically the `ThisProcess` variable content (the process name) like this:

```
MyProcess.exe (SWITCH)=(VALUE) (IN FILE)
```

So how I can manage the CDATA literal to set the variable content dynamically?

Is this possibly?

Maybe a better approach to manage this? (dynamically without hardcoding, keep in mind that it's for generic usage)

> UPDATE

I'm trying to reproduce @**Dan-o** solution but of course in my case don't works because it's a CDATA literal, then how to escape it or do the necessary modifications?:

```
        Dim ProcessName As String = "MyProcess.exe"

        Dim Help As XElement =
<Help>
    <Process><%= ProcessName %></Process>
    <Syntax><a><![CDATA[
[+] Syntax:

    <% ProcessName %> (SWITCH)=(VALUE) (IN FILE)
]]></a></Syntax>
</Help>

        Console.WriteLine(Help.<Process>.Value)
        Console.WriteLine(Help.<Syntax>.Value)
```

> UPDATE 2

In a simple XML file (for example, a .NET code snippet) I use this trick that I've learned time ago to scape a character in a CDATA:

```
<Literal Editable="false">
    <ID>cdataend</ID>
    <ToolTip>Part of the CDATA end tag.</ToolTip>
    <Default>&gt;</Default>
</Literal>
```

Then I could write the `>` illegal character inside, like this:

```
<Code Language="vb"><a><![CDATA[ something ]]$cdataend$</a>.Value ]]></Code>
```

The thing is that I don't know if that can help me with the variable issue... just I'm trying to give ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384752.aspx):

```
Dim contactName As String = "Patrick Hines" 
Dim contact As XElement = 
  <contact>
    <name><%= contactName %></name>
  </contact>
Console.WriteLine(contact)
```

It should be an extremely simple matter to adapt this to your situation.

Comment: Thankyou is usefull but how I could reproduce it inside of a CDATA literal?

Comment: I were trying it with the bad perspective, no CDATA is needed, so your solution is perfect, thanks again

Comment: well, not extremely simple. CDATA considers the variable notation as plain text.